# What is the recommended way to customize a component in Lazarus?

Tags: components, lazarus, uicomponents

I need to customize TStringGrid for my application. What is the recommended way to do it?

The only thing I have seen is to put the TMyStringGrid to a package, install it to IDE and than use it in my application. The problem is that I am working on that component at the same time as on the application and I do not want to reinstall the component every time I do any change in it just to test it.

When I tried to put it to my project it said: "Sharing code between packages and application source is not good idea."

Comment: I have just noticed that in package manager there is a button "Use>>" with submenu item "Add to project" which sound like someting which might help, however I have no idea how it is used.

Comment: The only way I found until now is to install the component and recompile it, reinstall + recompile whole Lazarus on any tiny change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing, don't use it designtime, but instantiate it runtime.

Comment: So I should not install it at all to Lazarus? (while testing) Is it what you suggest?

Comment: yes. Only if you really want to test behaviour in the designer, you need to install. For runtime behaviour not.